# php id encoding to have exact same character length for any given id

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, cryptography

i want to encode id such as customer id to unique string (alpha/numeric) to hide the id, also i want to keep encoded string to have same length always, say 16 characters. Also it should be decodable.

example:
id = 1
encoded id = abcd12345e6f7g80

id = 100000
encoded id = edfgj129j5e6j3gk9

Comment: Also i would like to keep alphabets in  only lowercase (0-9 a-z)

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution, I'm not sure if it's the best approche, but it does the job :

You can use [hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) to get a unique string with unified length for your `id`'s

```
$unique = hash('ripemd160', '1'); //c47907abd2a80492ca9388b05c0e382518ff3960
$unique = hash('ripemd160', '1000'); //1bf90630418c99622abb593907e904995196693f
```

Then you store the `id` and it's unique hash in a table that you can query any time. And this will be used to reverse the hash.

```
+-------+----------------------------------------+
|  id   |   hash                                 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+
|  1    |c47907abd2a80492ca9388b05c0e382518ff3960|
| ..    |...                                     |
+-------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks i wanted to avoid storing it in database. is there any other way?